# Remove roles and users from postgres AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql

I need to remove roles and users from postgres AWS RDS.

Can you please suggest on this issue, please share the queries for this.

Comment: Can't use DROP ROLE?

Answer (score 1):

If the account is authorised in postgres its just the same command as it would be in a normal postgres server:
`dropuser -h your.rds.db -U you SteBov` would hit me for example

for full details look here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-dropuser.html

dropping groups is near enough the same, documentation here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropgroup.html

Comment: I want revoke for particular user ,particular role like that am have 100 users and want to revoke some permissions for specified users at once   Is there any script for this

Comment: Is there a way to identify them within the database? from what you're saying here it sounds like you need a new group to allocate those users to and remove them from the current ones. Personally when I'm doing a large update on that scale I take all the entities to change into excel and then concatenate it with the command, so `alter group {group} drop username {user}` (with the connection details) then the associated add to the new group